# Dreamweaver automatically replacing symbols with HTML equivelent

Tags: dreamweaver

I often find that Dreamweaver has replaced symbols with the HTMl equivalent (for example, " with &guot;, > with `&gt;`). How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Why do you need to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this is the answer:
Edit - Preferences - Code Rewriting - Uncheck "encode <, >, &, and " in attribute values using &.

Answer (score 1):

Type in the code view instead of the WYSIWYG.

Comment: I have been typing in the code view...but thanks for answering!